# How to have multiple generic type paramters in blazor for a generic component

Tags: c#, components, blazor

I'm trying to create a Blazor component for filter purpose. The component contain a parameter of type generic list to contain a data list of specific type. As a render fragment, I have a "Filter Descriptors" which contain 1 to n child of type "Filter Descriptor".

In my "Filter Description" section, I actually have a "Member Name" parameter matching an existing property name of my generic type define at my component level. Depending of the data type of the "Member Name", I use different input control.

What I'm trying to do is having at the "Filter Descriptor" level:

1. A parameter which consist of a list of generic type
2. A parameter which matching a property name in the generic type (#1) for display purpose
3. A parameter which matching a property name of the generic type (#1) for value returning

If the parameter list is defined (#1), I will use a Combo List otherwise, I will an input component matching the data type of the "Member Name".

Regards
Al

```
`**Index.html:**
<MyComponent T="@typeof(Person)">
    <FilterDescritors>
        <FilterDescriptor MemberName="LastName" />
        <FilterDescriptor MemberName="DataOfBirth" />
        <FilterDescriptor MemberName="Hobby" ListData="@HobbyList" ListMemberName="HobbyName" ListMemberValue="HobbyName" />
        <FilterDescriptor MemberName="Sport" ListData="@SportList" ListMemberName="SportName" ListMemberValue="SportName" />
    </FilterDescriptors>
</MyComponent>

@code {
    public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
    public List<Hobby> HobbyList { get; set; }
    public List<Sport> SportList { get; set; }
    
    public class Person
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Hobby { get; set; }
        public string Sport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hobby
    {
        public string HobbyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sport
    {
        public string SportName { get; set; }
    }
}


**FilterDescriptor.cs:**
[Parameter]
public List<T2> ListData { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string ListMemberName { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string ListMemberValue { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string MemberName { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string MemberValue { get; set; }

**MyComponent.razor:**
@typeparam T

<My Component DataList="@DataList">

</My Component>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<T> DataList { get; set; }
}`
```

Comment: So which part of your description are you having trouble to implement?

Comment: The part where I'm trying to use a my FilterDescriptor with the ListData parameter. I'm trying without any success to defined properly the parameter. I need the parameter to be not mandatory. This parameter need to handle GenericType.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing in `MyComponent`, but here's a demo that shows you how to use delegates to solve the selection problem along with binding to update values in the parent.  You don't need to resort to reflection.  The demo page shows various ways of setting up the component.

*FilterSelector*

```cs
@typeparam TListItem
@typeparam TValue

<select @bind:get=this.Value
        @bind:set="(value) => this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value)"
        @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes>
    @if (this.Value is null)
    {
        <option selected disabled value=""> -- Select a Value -- </option>
    }
    @foreach (var item in this.Items)
    {
        <option value="@ValueDelegate?.Invoke(item)">@this.DisplayDelegate?.Invoke(item)</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TListItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<TListItem>();
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string>? DisplayDelegate { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string>? ValueDelegate { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Check we have the delegates set
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(DisplayDelegate);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ValueDelegate);
    }
}
```

Demo page

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>City Uid = @Uid </pre>
    <pre>Country 1 = @country1 </pre>
    <pre>Country 2 = @country2 </pre>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
        <FilterSelector class="form-select" Items="this.cities" @bind-Value=this.Uid ValueDelegate="(item) => item.Uid.ToString()" DisplayDelegate="(item) => item.Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
        <FilterSelector class="form-select" Items="this.countries" @bind-Value=this.country1 ValueDelegate="(item) => item" DisplayDelegate="(item) => item" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
        <FilterSelector class="form-select" Items="this.countries" @bind-Value=this.country2 ValueDelegate="(item) => item" DisplayDelegate="(item) => item" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid? Uid;
    private string? country1;
    private string? country2;

    private List<City> cities = new()
    {
        new() {Name="Paris", Country="France"},
        new() {Name="London", Country="UK"},
        new() {Name="Birmingham", Country="UK"},
        new() {Name="Lyon", Country="France"},
        new() {Name="Madrid", Country="Spain"},
         new() {Name="Lisbon", Country="Portugal"},
   };

    private List<string> countries = new() { "UK", "France", "Spain", "Portugal" };

    private IEnumerable<string> countryNames => cities.Select(item => item.Name).Distinct();

    public record City
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; init; } = "Not Set";
        public string Country { get; init; } = "Not Set";
    }
}
```

[image]